# Gurobi: Relaxing Infeasible Model in Python

Tags: python, gurobi, feasibility

I have the following constraint set in the mathematical notation of Gurobi. `x` variables are binary. `sigmaplus` and `sigmaminus` variables are positive and continuous.

```
Subject To
 858 x[1,_2] + 1092 x[1,_3] - sigmaplus[1] + sigmaminus[1] = -200  # Constraint 1
 858 x[1,_2] + 1092 x[1,_3] >= -1800 # Constraint 2
 858 x[1,_2] + 1092 x[1,_3] <= 0 # Constraint 3
 x[1,_2] + x[1,_3] = 1 # Constraint 4
 720 x[2,_1] + 990 x[2,_2] - sigmaplus[2] + sigmaminus[2] = 2000 # Constraint 5
 720 x[2,_1] + 990 x[2,_2] >= -500 # Constraint 6
 720 x[2,_1] + 990 x[2,_2] <= 3000 # Constraint 7
 x[2,_1] + x[2,_2] = 1 # Constraint 8
 ...
 ...
```

As you can notice, `constraint 2` and `constraint 3` make the solution infeasible. When, such a situation occurs with my `x` variables, I want Gurobi to do the optimization by setting those conflicting `x` values equal to 0. So, for this example, I want x`[1,2]` and `x[1,3]` to be equal to 0 in order to find a feasible solution without those variables. Is there any way to code this for `Gurobi 7.0.2`.

Also, I am using `2.7.12 Anaconda 4.2.0(64-bit)`. Following is the code that I use for relaxing the problem to find a solution.

```
if m.status == GRB.INFEASIBLE:
    m.feasRelaxS(1, False, False, True)
```

This works fine in some situation. I mean, it sets those infeasibility creating variables to 0. However, in some other cases where `constraints 1,2,` and `3` do not create any infeasibility, `constraint 4` creates an infeasibility, the solver increases the right-hand side of `Constraint 4`. So, I need to find a way to set them 0 in such cases. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
feasRelaxS ( relaxobjtype, minrelax, vrelax, crelax )
```

**Arguments:**

**relaxobjtype:** The cost function used when finding the minimum cost relaxation.

**minrelax:** The type of feasibility relaxation to perform.

**vrelax:** Indicates whether variable bounds can be relaxed.

**crelax:** Indicates whether constraints can be relaxed.

This function modifies the Model object to create a feasibility relaxation.
This method provides a number of options for specifying the relaxation.
The *minrelax* argument is a boolean that controls the type of feasibility relaxation that is created. If *minrelax*=False, optimizing the returned model gives a solution that minimizes the cost of the violation. If *minrelax*=True, optimizing the returned model finds a solution that minimizes the original objective, but only from among those solutions that minimize the cost of the violation. **If you want your model to relax variable value for which the constraint is infeasible, change *vrelax* from False to True.** You can read the full description given on: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/py_model_feasrelaxs.html